# How to see python logging output from child docker container (container started by another container)?

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, python-logging, dockerpy

I have an application that uses docker compose to start 3 containers. The logs for those 3 containers are outputted to `stdout` as expected. One of these containers is responsible for starting other containers, as they are needed. It uses [docker-py](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) to do that.

Those *secondary* containers are ephemeral, they run until the task is done and terminate. However I can't see their logging output.

- When I started, the `docker-compose` containers also weren't outputting logging to `stdout`, I had to use the following configs both in `Dockerfile` and the code:

```py
self.logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
level = logging.INFO
stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
self.logger.setLevel(level)
formatter = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s - %(name)s [%(levelname)s]: %(message)s")
stream_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
self.logger.addHandler(stream_handler)
```

Dockerfile

```
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
```

Now, I've tried to add the same settings in the code and `Dockerfile` for my *secondary* containers, this time though, it made no difference. It's possible that I may need to pass further instructions to `docker-py` when running the containers.

```py
network = self.docker_client.networks.get("service-daemon_default")
_ = self.docker_client.containers.run(
    image="default_image",
    detach=True,
    environment={
        "VENDOR_NAME": vendor,
        **self.settings.get("environment"),  # These are just REDIS configs, such as host, port , etc
    },
    name=vendor.lower(),
    network=network.name,
    auto_remove=self.settings.get("auto_destroy_containers", True),
)
```

Comment: If you run the intermediate container on its own, does it print the dynamically-generated containers' output?  (With `detach=True`, I might not expect it to.)  Docker doesn't have any notion of "parent" or "child" containers, and unless your top-level program can discover these other containers as they're created, this is actually kind of a tricky problem.

Comment: (Do you _need_ to start containers dynamically?  Can you use a work-queue system like Celery to add tasks, and have some number of long-running worker containers to do the work?  That wouldn't be Docker-specific, you'd avoid the security issues around the Docker socket, and you could see the workers' logs normally.)